# Обобщить наследуемые классы в абстрактном JAVA

Tags: java, наследование, шаблоны-проектирования, рефакторинг

Нужно обобщить два класса. Есть абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class AbstractRobot extends UpdatableUnit {
    // --------------------------- Перемещение ------------------------------------
    public abstract boolean canMoveTo(Cell to);

    public abstract void move(Direction direct);
}
```

А также два наследующих класса:

```
public class StrongRobot extends AbstractRobot  {
    // --------------------------- Перемещение ------------------------------------
    @Override
    public boolean canMoveTo(Cell to) {return true;}

    @Override
    public void move(Direction direct) {

// Сделать вытаскивание предмета из ячейки, если ячейка не пустая, и переход в нее

        Cell pos = typedOwner();

        Cell newPos = pos.neighbor(direct);
        if(newPos == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(!canMoveTo(newPos)) {
            newPos.extractUnit();
        }

        pos.extractUnit();

        newPos.putUnit(this);

        fireStateChanged();
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String msg;
        msg = "R(∞)";

        return msg;
    }
}
```

И, соответственно:

```
public class SimpleRobot extends AbstractRobot {

    // ------------------------------- Заряд ---------------------------------
    private int _charge = 25;
    
    private static final int REQUIRED_CHARGE_FOR_MOVE = 1;
    
    public int charge() {
        return _charge;
    }
    
    public boolean isAvailableCharge(int chargeQuery) {
        return chargeQuery <= _charge;
    }
    
    protected int reduceCharge(int chargeQuery) {
        int retrievedCharge = Math.min(_charge, chargeQuery);
        _charge -= retrievedCharge;
        return retrievedCharge;
    }

    // --------------------------- Перемещение ------------------------------------
    @Override
    public boolean canMoveTo(Cell to) {
        return to.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void move(Direction direct) {
       
        Cell pos = typedOwner();
        
        if(!isAvailableCharge(REQUIRED_CHARGE_FOR_MOVE)) {
            return;
        }
        
        Cell newPos = pos.neighbor(direct);
        if(newPos == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(!canMoveTo(newPos)) {
            return;
        }
        
        pos.extractUnit();
        newPos.putUnit(this);
        reduceCharge(REQUIRED_CHARGE_FOR_MOVE);

        fireStateChanged();
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String msg;
        msg = "R(" + charge() + ")";

        return msg;
    }
}
```

Как вы могли заметить, перемещение в этих двух классах совпадает на 80%. Цель - обобщить классы, то есть вынести в абстрактный класс перемещение.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, обобщение классов в Java обозначает скорее параметризацию класса неким общим типом `T`, то есть в названии класса появляется указание на *общий* (generic) тип: `public abstract class AbstractRobot<T> extends UpdatableUnit<T>`

В данном же случае требуется вынести *некий общий функционал* из реализаций абстрактных методов в класс-родитель, то есть использовать паттерн [шаблонный метод (template method)](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/template-method) для рефакторинга поведения в методе `move`.

Соответственно, метод `move` переносится в класс-родитель и перестаёт быть абстрактным, однако в нём должны быть добавлены вызовы других-методов, в которых следует реализовать "подшаги", чтобы можно было реализовать существующие различия в логике между реализациями `StrongRobot` и `SimpleRobot`.
Если "подшаги" определены как абстрактные методы, то их понадобится переопределять при помощи заглушек в классах, где они не требуются, поэтому может быть лучше определить эти заглушки в родительском классе.

```java
public abstract class AbstractRobot extends UpdatableUnit {

    public abstract boolean canMoveTo(Cell to);

    public void move(Direction direct) {
        if(!checkCondition()) {
            return;
        }
        
        Cell pos = typedOwner();
        
        Cell newPos = pos.neighbor(direct);
        if(newPos == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(!canMoveTo(newPos)) {
            return;
        }
        
        pos.extractUnit();
        newPos.putUnit(this);

        afterMove();

        fireStateChanged();
    }

    /**
        Метод для проверки условия движения
        @return true если движение разрешено
     */
    protected boolean checkCondition() { return true; }

    /**
        Метод для вызова перед отправкой события stateChanged
      */
    protected void afterMove() {}
}
```

Соответственно, реализация метода `move` в классе `StrongRobot` удаляется и заглушки для реализации шагов `checkCondition` / `afterMove` не нужны.

А в классе `SimpleRobot` потребуется переопределить только "подшаги":

```java
public class SimpleRobot extends AbstractRobot {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected boolean checkCondition() { 
        return isAvailableCharge(REQUIRED_CHARGE_FOR_MOVE); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterMove() {
        reduceCharge(REQUIRED_CHARGE_FOR_MOVE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, не лучший вариант, но можно сделать и так.

1. В абстрактный класс помещаете метод `move()` и выносите туда всё общее (В абстрактном классе могут быть неабстрактные методы).
2. В каждом классе-наследники переопределяете метод `move()`, а первой строчкой вызываете метод из суперкласса с помощью `super()`:

```java
public void move(Direction direct) {
    super.move(direct);
    //Какие-то специфичные действия для конкретного объекта
}
```